# gsutil command to move files over a certain age?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

On my Google VM disk I'm creating various video files.

The video files need to be accessible on my disk for an hour, but after that period, I want to move them to a Google Cloud bucket.

What would the gsutil command be to copy/move files over a certain age?

Currently I'm storing the creation of these videos in a database and calling a script that generates the filenames to be moved. But surely gsutil can do this for me using the file's age?

Comment: `gsutil` does not do any special processing of local files (e.g., `gsutil cp` works more or less like `cp` which also doesn't query file timestamps), so you would need to generate the list of files externally, or via a shell script which would look at the modification times of the files, or as you do via querying the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you can incorporate a timestamp into the start of your object names you could list objects in age order and then copy/move ones older than some threshold.